# Could not resolve property error when debugging application

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im totally new to springboot and it get these errors when i try debugging them. They include;

```
could not resolve property: orderID of: com.DigitalVision.service.models.DeliveryStatus

could not resolve property: orderID of: com.DigitalVision.service.models.DeliveryStatus [Select s from com.DigitalVision.service.models.DeliveryStatus s where s.orderID = ?1]
Among a few of them, some included that there was an error creating bean with name deliveryStatusRepository.
```

Courier controller class

```
package com.DigitalVision.service.controllers;

import com.DigitalVision.service.models.Courier;
import com.DigitalVision.service.services.CourierService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/courier")
@Service
public class CourierController

{

    private CourierService courierService;
    @Autowired
    public CourierController(CourierService courierService) {
        this.courierService = courierService;
    }


    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(path = "/update-status/{status}/order-id/{orderId}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity getAttendanceByDateRange(@PathVariable("status") String status,
                                                   @PathVariable("orderId") Long orderId) throws Exception {

        Courier courier = courierService.updatestatus(status,orderId);
        if (courier == null ) {

            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(courier, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }


}
```

I have not done a controller class for the delivery status one yet

Courier class

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Courier implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long CourierID;
    public  Long OrderID;
    public  String Status;
```

Delivery status

```
@Entity
@Table
public class DeliveryStatus implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long DeliveryStatusID;
    public Long OrderID;
    public String Status;
    public LocalDate Date;
```

Order class

```
public class Order implements Serializable {

    public Long OrderID;
    public Long CustomerID;
    public Long ProductID;
    public String Quantity;
```

Deliverystatusrepository

```
import com.DigitalVision.service.models.DeliveryStatus;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface DeliveryStatusRepository extends JpaRepository<DeliveryStatus, Long> {

    @Query("Select s from DeliveryStatus s where s.orderID = ?1")
    DeliveryStatus findDeliveryStatusIDByOrderID(Long id);


}
```

Courier service

```
 public Courier updatestatus(String Status, Long courierID){
        Courier courier = courierRepository.getReferenceById(courierID);
        courier.setStatus(Status);
        Courier courierSave = courierRepository.save(courier);
        if(courierSave == null ){

            return null;
        }
       
        deliveryStatusService.updatestatus(courierSave);
        return courierSave;
    }
```

Delivery status service

```
public DeliveryStatus updatestatus (Courier courier ){
        DeliveryStatus deliveryStatus = deliveryStatusRepository.findDeliveryStatusIDByOrderID(courier.OrderID);
        deliveryStatus.setStatus(courier.Status);
        return deliveryStatusRepository.save(deliveryStatus);
    }
```

The purpose of this code is to automatically change the status in the deliverystatus table when the courier status column is updated.
If anyone can help me find the error it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In Java, variable names should be `lowerCamelCase`, not `UpperCamelCase`. There is nothing wrong with the latter, it's convention, and Spring is [Convention over configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s10.html). Probably by changing this the error will go away. What is happening is that the repository call `findDeliveryStatusIDByOrderID` is looking for the property `orderID` as you see in the trace, but you have `OrderID`. If you don't want to change your models then change the `@Query` so it looks for `s.OrderID` instead of `s.orderID`.

Comment: I think that worked because no errors have come up yet but it seems to be taking forever to debug. Been about 20 mins now and its last log entry is               
HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=48s242ms415µs300ns). Is this somethin i should worry about? @JettoMartínez

Comment: Seems like a connection leak. That is totally different. To your `application.properties` file, add `logging.level.ROOT=debug`, restart the project and try again. You will see more output in the console and perhaps youll have a better idea of the new problem if it occurs again. If that's the case, you'll need to do some research and if you can't figure out, come back to StackOverflow with a new question.